# Adapt <frame> height to its content

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive, frames, frameset

I am using two frames as if to split my screen in two. As far as I know, I can only define the height of the frames (rows) by specifying  the percentage for each one. I really can't seem to find a way to make the size of the first frame automatically adapt to the height of its content. Tried to play a bit with 100%, auto, margin-bottom etc but nothing worked! Please help

Here's my code:

*html:*

```
 <html>
   <frameset rows="9%,91%">
   <frame src="header.htm">
   <frame src="content.htm">
   </frameset>
 </html>
```

*htm ('header' body):*

```
<body class='project1'>
         <div class="information">
   <div class="navigation"> Navigation menu </div>
   <div class="project-information">Project info</div>
         </div>
</body>
```

*css:*

```
.project1 {
background-color: #f1f1f1;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow-x: hidden;
}

.information {
font-family: "Times New Roman";
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
padding-bottom: 10px;
overflow-x: hidden;
top: 0px;
padding: 10px;
z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to 2018. Please don't use framesets.

Comment: Please, read this http://www.rwblackburn.com/iframe-evil/

Comment: Adding on to @BenM, the reason you should not use `frameset` and `frame` is they have been [REMOVED](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frameset) from the HTML5 standard. Browsers could stop rendering them at any time.

Comment: understood, thanks